# How to change line colors of chart in Chartist.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, chartist.js

I'm currently using `Chartist.js`, But I can't change the default line colors of Chart.
[Chartist.js](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html)

[image: Sample Chart Image]

For `SIMPLE LINE CHART` I've tried:

```
.ct-series-a .ct-line{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

But It brings no result. How to fix this?

Comment: This question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35402143/using-chartist-js-how-do-you-change-the-color-of-the-stroke-for-a-donut-chart. You need to override the correct css classes (they are slightly longer than yours).

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
.ct-series-a .ct-line {
  /* Set the colour of this series line */
  stroke: red;
  /* Control the thikness of your lines */
  stroke-width: 5px;
  /* Create a dashed line with a pattern */
  stroke-dasharray: 10px 20px;
}
```

https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/getting-started.html#customizing-the-default-css

Comment: Diego, you can add some explanation to enrich the resolution for future use.

Comment: Is it possible to use background image ?