# How to color the chart background in chartist.js

Tags: css, chartist.js

I may be missing something simple but I cannot change the background color of the chart using chartist.js

```
.ct-grid {
background: black;
background-color: black;
stroke:black;
fill:black;
}
```

I am trying to change just the grid area, not the entire area hence I am not using `ct-chart ct-golden-section`

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this question has been answered already, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493564/chart-area-background-color-chartjs)

Comment: @Agrendallan that is for chart.js not chartist.js

Comment: Doesn't it work in the same fashion? If not this seems to be a solution for chartist [This maybe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43432120/how-to-change-line-colors-of-chart-in-chartist-js#47580846)

Comment: Your solution is for the lines, I am looking to change the color of the graph itself (like your first suggestion - but for chartist.js)

Comment: I think you could use fill for changing the whole background, basically filling the rectangle that is your background. Which is achieved by using the "fill" css property.

Answer (score 0):

The below might give you an idea of how to proceed .. maybe use some css like the `calc()` to find the right sizes so that you don't set them statically

```
.ct-golden-section:before {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    content: "";
    width: 100%; 
    height: 413px; //set as the size of the container
    padding-bottom: 449px; //set as the size of the container
    background: yellow; // set the bg color wanted for the container
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 15px;
    border-left-width: 49px;
    border-color: orange;  // choose the color of the page u have
    border-bottom-width: 25px;
    border-right-width: 39px;
}
```

Check the screenshot to see the result of the above:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15-vuRMXn2NspkNWfIuvcEZ8xxOEUeEgd/view?usp=sharing

Please anyone feel free to edit my temporary solution

Comment: Hmm, is there a reason for the `:before`, also why would we not be able to use `ct-grids` to then change background/fill/background-color. It seems like there should be a much simpler solution

Answer (score 0):

From version 0.11.4 you can use option showGridBackground: true and then set from css.For example

```
.ct-grid-background {
        fill: aliceblue;
 }
```

[You can read more information there](https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/issues/711)